# Problem with dovecot login, how can I fix failed login?

Tags: authentication, dovecot

I have a terrible problem with logging into `dovecot`.

- This is my `/usr/local/etc/dovecot/passdb` (just one single entry with plain password):

  ```
  fritz@myhost.com{PLAIN}asdf::::::
  ```
- When I run dovecot auth login from the shell like this:

  ```
  dovecot auth login fritz@myhost.com asdf
  ```

  I get

  ```shellsession
  # dovecot auth login fritz@myhost.com          
  Password:                                                              
  passdb: fritz@myhost.com auth failed                                   
  extra fields:                                                          
    user=fritz@myhost.com                                                
  root@mail:/home/webhost # dovecot auth login fritz@myhost.com asdf     
  passdb: fritz@myhost.com auth failed                                   
  extra fields:                                                          
    user=fritz@myhost.com
  ```
- In order to debug this I've set

  ```
  auth_verbose = yes                  
  auth_verbose_passwords = yes
  ```

  in my `/usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`
- In my log file I get this output, which doesn't really help much:

  ```
  2023-03-03 09:08:25 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH        1       PLAIN   service=doveadm debug   resp=ZnJpdHpAbXlob3N0LmNvbQBmcml0ekBteWhvc3QuY29tAGF
  zZGY= (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
  2023-03-03 09:08:25 auth: Debug: passwd-file(fritz@myhost.com): Performing passdb lookup
  2023-03-03 09:08:25 auth: Debug: passwd-file(fritz@myhost.com): lookup: user=fritz@myhost.com file=/usr/local/etc/dovecot/passdb
  2023-03-03 09:08:25 auth: Info: passwd-file(fritz@myhost.com): unknown user (given password: asdf)
  2023-03-03 09:08:25 auth: Debug: passwd-file(fritz@myhost.com): Finished passdb lookup
  2023-03-03 09:08:25 auth: Debug: auth(fritz@myhost.com): Auth request finished
  2023-03-03 09:08:27 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL        1       user=fritz@myhost.com
  ```

I'm totally stuck and have no clue, what else I could possibly do to fix this.